# How to change the favicon using nano react app?

Tags: reactjs, favicon

I'm wondering how to change the default favicon on the browser tab using a nano react app and displaying it on localhost. I've already tried the whole process using https://realfavicongenerator.net/ but I don't have the static nor the public folder since it's a nano project... I'm not sure it's possible either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have generated the favicon, but have not linked it to the html page. Here is the structure of the project as per the [documentation on their github repo](https://github.com/nano-react-app/nano-react-app).

[image]

Here the index.html file is in the project root folder. To get it working, you can place your favicon alongside it, and in index.html you can add `<link rel="icon" href="./favicon-filename" />`

Since the project uses Parcel, it will find the favicon during the build process.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually made it :)

Comment: My suggestion is fine for a small app, but if the project is big, it would be best to create an `assets` folder, or follow some other maintainable folder structure.

Comment: Great! Thanks again :)

Comment: In case I wanted to change the favicon depending on using light mode or night mode on the browser?